# Android custom textview

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, lib

I need textview where first letter is big capatalized like on the photo. What is the best library or solution to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: The big letter is called a drop cap. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3664, https://github.com/novoda/spikes/tree/master/drop-cap

Comment: thanks man it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Add following dependency in app/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.rpradal.lettrine:lettrine:release_number'
```

**2.** Use LettrineTextView

```
<com.github.rpradal.lettrine.LettrineTextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:lettrine_textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
              app:lettrine_text="Lorem ipsum"
              app:lettrine_lettrineSize="3"
              app:lettrine_textSize="14sp" />
```

For more help, please follow [this](https://github.com/rpradal/Lettrine) link

Result will be as:

[image]

Comment: how to adjust line spacing in this lib?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpannableString` without using any library.

```
  String title = "This is a very good thing. You should try with that and suggest to others";
  final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(title);
  int position = 0;
  for (int i = 0, ei = title.length(); i < ei; i++) {
        char c = title.charAt(i);
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

  spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), position, position + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  txt.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

You can use your text in `title` variable.

Comment: It's good solution but first letter behavious not like on the image.